# How to save query result to file using PgAdmin to terminal

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a way to write a script in pgAdmin that will save results of a number of queries to csv files?
Like result of query1 saved to1.csv, query 2 to 2. csv etc.
I could do it manually by running query one by one and clicking "save as", but how to do it in a script?

I expect a number of csv files containing results of queries, but without manually clicking one by one, but using a script in PgAdmin.

Comment: Use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and `\pset format csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using COPY command like this:

```
COPY test TO '/home/someuser/results/test.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

all the contents of test table to a csv file, or a query

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM test WHERE id >1) TO '/home/someuser/results/test.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

> The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the
> server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of
> the server.

that means the postgres user (the user that runs the postgreSQL process) must have writing permission on the folder where the results will be stored and that folder or path resides on the server side, that works with any database manager, not just pgAdmin. For more info check the [official docs for COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

To execute COPY command a user needs to have granted the role `pg_write_server_files` however is necessary take into account the following:

> The pg_read_server_files, pg_write_server_files and
> pg_execute_server_program roles are intended to allow administrators
> to have trusted, but non-superuser, roles which are able to access
> files and run programs on the database server as the user the database
> runs as. As these roles are able to access any file on the server file
> system, they bypass all database-level permission checks when
> accessing files directly and they could be used to gain
> superuser-level access, therefore great care should be taken when
> granting these roles to users.